# Encoding foreign alphabet characters

Tags: python, encoding

I am getting data from an XML provided by an API that for some reason lists Czechslovak characters in a different encoding (e.g. instead of correct Czechoslovak "***ý***" it uses "***Ã½***"). Therefore, instead of providing the

correct output to the user -> ***"Zelený"***

the output is -> ***"ZelenÃ½"***

I went through multiple StackOverflow posts, other fora and tutorials, but I still cannot figure out how to make it turn ***"ZelenÃ½"*** into ***"Zelený"*** (this is just one of the weird characters used by the XML so I cannot use str.replace).

I figured out, that the correct encoding for the Czech/Slovak language is "*windows-1250*"

My code:

```
def change_encoding(what):
    what = what.encode("windows-1250")
    return what

clean_xml_input = change_encoding(xml_input)
```

This produces error:

> 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 5-6: character
> maps to <undefined>

Comment: Are you using the API the right way? Does it come from a webserver? Chances are that you're requesting it wrong or reading the response wrong. Web servers typically provide the encoding already.

Answer (score 0):

```py
"ZelenÃ½".encode("Windows-1252").decode("utf-8") #'Zelený'
"ZelenÃ½".encode("windows-1254").decode("utf-8") #'Zelený'
"ZelenÃ½".encode("iso-8859-1").decode("utf-8") #'Zelený'
"ZelenÃ½".encode("iso-8859-9").decode("utf-8") #'Zelený'
```

If it is helpful

```py
from itertools import permutations
all_encoding = ['ASMO-708',
 'big5',
 'cp1025',
 'cp866',
 'cp875',
 'csISO2022JP',
 'DOS-720',
 'DOS-862',
 'EUC-CN',
 'EUC-JP',
 'euc-jp',
 'euc-kr',
 'GB18030',
 'gb2312',
 'hz-gb-2312',
 'IBM00858',
 'IBM00924',
 'IBM01047',
 'IBM01140',
 'IBM01141',
 'IBM01142',
 'IBM01143',
 'IBM01144',
 'IBM01145',
 'IBM01146',
 'IBM01147',
 'IBM01148',
 'IBM01149',
 'IBM037',
 'IBM1026',
 'IBM273',
 'IBM277',
 'IBM278',
 'IBM280',
 'IBM284',
 'IBM285',
 'IBM290',
 'IBM297',
 'IBM420',
 'IBM423',
 'IBM424',
 'IBM437',
 'IBM500',
 'ibm737',
 'ibm775',
 'ibm850',
 'ibm852',
 'IBM855',
 'ibm857',
 'IBM860',
 'ibm861',
 'IBM863',
 'IBM864',
 'IBM865',
 'ibm869',
 'IBM870',
 'IBM871',
 'IBM880',
 'IBM905',
 'IBM-Thai',
 'iso-2022-jp',
 'iso-2022-jp',
 'iso-2022-kr',
 'iso-8859-1',
 'iso-8859-13',
 'iso-8859-15',
 'iso-8859-2',
 'iso-8859-3',
 'iso-8859-4',
 'iso-8859-5',
 'iso-8859-6',
 'iso-8859-7',
 'iso-8859-8',
 'iso-8859-8-i',
 'iso-8859-9',
 'Johab',
 'koi8-r',
 'koi8-u',
 'ks_c_5601-1987',
 'macintosh',
 'shift_jis',
 'us-ascii',
 'utf-16',
 'utf-16BE',
 'utf-32',
 'utf-32BE',
 'utf-7',
 'utf-8',
 'windows-1250',
 'windows-1251',
 'Windows-1252',
 'windows-1253',
 'windows-1254',
 'windows-1255',
 'windows-1256',
 'windows-1257',
 'windows-1258',
 'windows-874',
 'x-Chinese-CNS',
 'x-Chinese-Eten',
 'x-cp20001',
 'x-cp20003',
 'x-cp20004',
 'x-cp20005',
 'x-cp20261',
 'x-cp20269',
 'x-cp20936',
 'x-cp20949',
 'x-cp50227',
 'x-EBCDIC-KoreanExtended',
 'x-Europa',
 'x-IA5',
 'x-IA5-German',
 'x-IA5-Norwegian',
 'x-IA5-Swedish',
 'x-iscii-as',
 'x-iscii-be',
 'x-iscii-de',
 'x-iscii-gu',
 'x-iscii-ka',
 'x-iscii-ma',
 'x-iscii-or',
 'x-iscii-pa',
 'x-iscii-ta',
 'x-iscii-te',
 'x-mac-arabic',
 'x-mac-ce',
 'x-mac-chinesesimp',
 'x-mac-chinesetrad',
 'x-mac-croatian',
 'x-mac-cyrillic',
 'x-mac-greek',
 'x-mac-hebrew',
 'x-mac-icelandic',
 'x-mac-japanese',
 'x-mac-korean',
 'x-mac-romanian',
 'x-mac-thai',
 'x-mac-turkish',
 'x-mac-ukrainian']

for i,j in permutations(all_encoding, 2):
    try:
        if("ZelenÃ½".encode(i).decode(j) == 'Zelený'):
            print(f'encode with `{i}` and decode with `{j}`')
    except:
        pass
```